# Bootstrap navbar not working in mob view the dropdown menu is not showing when I am clicking the button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg mt-md-4 navbar-dark">
  <div class="container px-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="./img/icon-assets/purple-tutor-logo.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <div class="mr-auto"></div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item" data-interval="3000">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">How it Works</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">School Registration</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link btn btn-lg btn-nav"
            href="https://study.purpletutor.com/register"
            >Get a FREE TRIAL!</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

this is my navbar can someone please tell me what the error is why in mob view the collapse menu is not showing when I click the button

this is the script I am using and I am using bootstrap 4 cdn can someone please help me out I already checked multiple posts on stack overflow already

```
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no errors on your code, you are only missing jquery included for the dropdown to work on mobile, please add it before the bootstrap script like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Comment: can you please remove your answer I need to delete this question